# Specify a list of values for a key in Lift framework config

Tags: scala, configuration, config, configuration-files, lift

In scala-lift v2.6, `src/main/resources/app/confg/parameters.conf` looks very much like a json:

```
env_type {

  dev {
    greeting = "greeting: dev"

    lift {
      runMode = "development"
    }

    dryRun = true
    etlPrune = false

    testMode = true
  }
}
```

Is there any way to specify a list of values for a certain key in such config format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format is a JSON superset called [HOCON](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#using-hocon-the-json-superset) ("Human-Optimized Config Object Notation"), which is what the Typesafe Config library uses.

To specify multiple values for a key, use square brackets and commas. For example:

```
env_type {
  dev {
    names = ["dev", "sandbox", "alt-prod"]
  }
}
```

To get `names` in your application code:

```
val conf = ConfigFactory.load
val devNames = conf.getStringList("env_type.dev.names") // java.util.List[String]
```